# Create a form with the column names of a database table

Tags: php

I have a table in my database with columns created by the user via a form. So I don't know the column names. I should create a form with the fields that are just given by the names of the columns created. How can I do? So I should get the name and type of the columns in a table in my database.

Comment: `I have a table in my database with columns created by the user via a form`...for what reason? This isn't something you need to do in 99% of applications.

Comment: Mine is a university project, nothing official @ADyson

Comment: That's irrelevant. The point is why you think you need such a feature? The reason you're writing the application doesn't really matter, it's still a good idea to do things in the most sensible way.

Comment: Are you trying to remake something like `phpMyAdmin`? The described requirement is too complex for a single SO question.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_community", 'oldboot', 'bigkev123');
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$sql = "SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='my_database_name' AND `TABLE_NAME`='my_table_name'";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$columns = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach($columns as $col)
{
        echo '<input type="text" name="'.$col['COLUMN_NAME'].'>';
}
```

This is rather simplistic, as it does not allow for different types of inputs. But will get you on the way. Feel free to ask more.